# Unable to authenticate to Azure DevOps using Personal Access Token (302 redirect)

Tags: rest, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, power-automate

I followed the Azure DevOps docs for how to create a [Personal Access Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows#use-a-pat-in-your-code), convert the token to Base64 and [GET repo branches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), but I cannot successfully request.

What am I missing?

**PowerAutomate Action:** HTTP Request

- Where `myOrg, myProject and myRepoID` are actual values

[image]

**Error:** 302 Redirect

[image]

**Error Text:**

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://spsprodcus3.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signin?realm=dev.azure.com&amp;reply_to=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.azure.com%2FmyOrg%2FmyProject%2F_apis%2Fgit%2Frepositories%2FmyRepoID%2Frefs%3Fapi-version%3D6.0&amp;redirect=1&amp;hid=<longGUID>&amp;context=<longGUIDctx=<longGUID">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

**EDIT 1:**

- Tried adding the `Content-Type` header and adding the auth as a special header
- Still same error

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

- Tried adding the PAT to Basic auth but the Username is required

[image]

**EDIT 3:**

- I found that even though above action fails, the response `Location` header contains a URL that resolves correctly:

  - `https://spsprodcus3.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signin?realm=dev.azure.com&reply_to=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.azure.com%2FmyOrg%2FmyProject%2F_apis%2Fgit%2Frepositories%3Fapi-version%3D6.0&redirect=1&mkt=en-US&hid=LONG_GUID&context=LONG_GUIDctx=LONG_GUID`
- **BUT** when this URL is piped to a subsequent HTTP action, it results in a 203 response that does not include the REST response!

[image]

**EDIT 4:** THIS WORKED

- Added a `.` to the `Basic` username Authentication
- Regenerated the ADO Personal Access Token, saved the new value in Key Vault

[image]

Comment: Try to change Authentication to `Basic Auth` and add your PAT as the password. Username can be blank

Comment: Hm. @GeralexGR, Username can not be blank. See **EDIT 1** above

Comment: Enter `.` as the username. The value is ignored.

Comment: Just tested, please see **EDIT 4** in OP. Same response as putting the `Authorization  Bearer <PAT>`: Redirect 312. How can I get a JSON response from the Azure DevOps REST API?

Comment: EH...regenerated the Personal Access Token, saved it as a new version of Key Vault secret, re-submitted the flow...works! No redirects, nothing, just a nice, clean, **Status 200**! Go ahead and write up the answer and I'll award the bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you @[GeralexGR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1509124/geralexgr) and @[jessehouwing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736079/jessehouwing) , @[***SeaDude***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5976033/seadude) ***as you have confirmed your solution ,I am posting it as an answer to help other Community members for the similar issue so they can find and fix their issue as you have mentioned in comment.***

> I followed the Azure DevOps docs for how to create a Personal Access
> Token, convert the token to Base64 and GET repo branches, but I cannot
> successfully request.
>
> What am I missing?

***To achieve the above requirement try to add Authentication  as `BASIC` and user add `.`*** .

And

> ***Regenerate ADO Personal Access Token and save the new value in your Key Vault secret and resubmit flow***.

[image]

For more information please refer this [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app?tabs=azure-portal#authentication-types-for-triggers-and-actions-that-support-authentication).

Comment: Technically, the bounty should be @jessehouwing's. But since he didn't write up an answer after 5 days, you can have it.

Comment: Username can be empty. The important thing is to convert the string `:<your_password>` in base 64 (note the `:` at the beginning of the string)